# Convert integer to hours and minutes

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python script that will read a file and grab a string `total_time`. Currently, this is what I have.

```
if("Total time" in data):
                total_time=int(filter(str.isdigit, data))
                print(total_time)
```

Output: 419

I'm trying to find the best way to read lots of files, grab this total time, and convert 419 into 4 hours and 19 minutes to allow me to do some statics and analytics with this.

Comment: try converting 4 hours 19 minutes to python datetime object. Also what is the type of the file you are trying to read ? better to convert txt into csv, you may then leverage the power of pandas and dataframes

Comment: Better than what? You aren't actually showing an approach to solving your problem...

Comment: What does `data` look like? Since `data` is a string you should simply use regex to extract hours and minutes individually instead of concatenating them into an integer of no meaningful value.

Comment: The file is an org file and I've debated how to grab the data and read the total time.  Here is what the string looks like in the file | *Total time* | *4:19* |      |
|--------------+--------+------|

Answer (score 4):

Passing [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) argument to datetime in Pandas:

```
t="419"
a = pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H%M')
print(a.hour)
print(a.minute)
```

Comment: This works except the output also shows a year, month, and day. Is there a way to only print the hours and minutes?

Comment: print(a.hour) and print(a.minute) prints the hour and minute. You need to extract the hour and minute from the timestamp

Comment: If you want it of the format hour:minute, you can concatenate the output as a.hour+":"+a.minute

Answer (score 2):

Given some string set as

```
s = '419'
```

you can get the upper and lower digits by converting to an integer, then using modulo and integer division. The integer conversion can be encapsulated in a `try-except` block catching `ValueError` if you have a reasonable response to invalid inputs:

```
n = int(s)
hours = n // 100  # Truncating integer division
minutes = n % 100  # Modulo removes the upper digits
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `divmod()` seems appropriate here!

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 3
>>> divmod(a,b) # (a // b, a % b)
(1,2)
```

For your specific situation:

```
def dataToTime(data):
    ''' Returns a list of (hour, minute) tuples from
        a list of strings '''
    total_times = filter(str.isdigit,data)
    return [divmod(int(time),100) for time in total_times]
```

If you would like to parse the data as you are inputting it try the `re` module which has the method `re.sub()` for regex substitution

```
>>> import re

>>> s = '| Total time | 4:19 | | |--------------+--------+------| –'
>>> h = int(re.sub(r':.*$|[^0-9]','',s))
>>> m = int(re.sub(r'^.*:|[^0-9]','',s))
>>> print h,m
(4,19)
```